# What are popular test functions for root-finding algorithms?

Tags: reference-request, roots

In Wikipedia, there is a list of popular test functions for optimization problems https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_functions_for_optimization, but for root finding, I've found only Wilkinson's polynomial...